# Domain Redirect Missing Slash for full URLs

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, centos7

I have 2 old servers, which I am not using any more, which have been replaced by 1 new system, and I want anyone who tries to go to the old domain names, to be redirected to the new one.

So, for example, anyone who tries to go to **a.mydomain.com** or **b.mydomain.com** should be redirected to **new.mydomain.com**

What was done was that a member of the network team simply changed the IP address associated with **a.mydomain.com** and **b.mydomain.com** names to point to the new server, where **new.mydomain.com** is being served.

This works fine if you go to the top level, e.g. if I go to http://a.mydomain.com it will redirect to http://new.mydomain.com perfectly fine.

However, if I try to go to a full file URL of the old name, e.g. http://a.mydomain.com/file.php, instead of redirecting to http://new.mydomain.com/file.php, it redirects to: http://new.mydomain.comfile.php (Missing the slash "/" ) and therefore obviously fails, because that's not a valid url.

They said it was a server configuration thing, so I've tried messing around with the virtualhost on the new server. I've tried using the old domains as ServerAliases, i've also tried actually just setting them up as separate virtualhosts to point to the same document root, but I am still experiencing the same problem each time.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? And if it's something I need to change on the server, or if it's something the network team need to change in the DNS?

(I am using CentOS and Apache)

Thanks.

Edit:

This is what the virtualhost on the **new** server looked like originally:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moodleportal
ServerName new.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried adding in a new virtualhost to serve the old domain name and test pointing it to a different documentroot, e.g.

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test
ServerName a.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And I even commented out the new.mydomain.com virtualhost, but whichever domain you go to in the browser it goes to the same documentroot.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out they had changed the external IP records but not internal.